# Identifying and Removing unwanted CSS (files/styles) and JS(scripts/functions) from a browsing session of a domain

Tags: javascript, css, profiling

We have a very large project using twitter bootstrap templates and third party jQuery plugins, the original developer added several plugins and CSS files without caring about the features and functions that he will be using.

As some of these styles and JS functions can be called dynamically and as the project is very very large doing manual checks is a very tedious job, so are you aware of any tools that can profile the usage of both the CSS and JS functions for a browsing session (lets assume the browsing session covers all the pages and js functions and clicks) and report the unused ones so that developers can remove them safely at the build stage into production to keep the payload to the minimum?

The above is valid for any site not just the ones using bootstrap templates and jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that with Chrome's Audits, you can check what percentage of your `CSS` files are being used, that would help narrow it down; only for certain pages though.

[image: Chrome's Audits]

Sometimes the best way for doing a cleanup is just choosing a design (features/styles/etc.) and dropping the rest, it may break functionality and appearance on the system and it may be tedious, but at least you know the job is done right then.

Some of you may probably disagree, but this would be the way I would tackle the job.

Comment: I accept this as answer for the partial help it provides in identifying the unused CSS for a given page. Ideally I am looking to see if there is a tool that does it for a browsing session against a domain i.e. multiple pages so that the code on the server for that domain can be cleared out easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your questions here entirely, but *Chrome* as well as *Firefox* have very good profiling tools (*Developer Tools*, respectively *FireBug*) which will provide you a very good overview of used *ECMAscript* code / methods and times + performance.

If you're asking how to remove stylesheets and/or Javascript dynamically during a session, its very simple. Its no problem at all to remove *CSS* / *Stylesheets* (those will get removed from memory and will lose any link to the site). The trouble begins with the Javascript, there is no way to *remove / unload* a once loaded code of Javascript dynamically. You certainly can remove the `<script>` element for instance, but the code will stay in memory and in effect for ever.

Comment: I am looking for a tool to identify unused CSS and JS from a browser session of a Domain i.e. I might navigate to several pages in a domain and the tool should list out unused JS functions and CSS classes. Epoch's answer above provides partial help towards this cause. I would love to see any other tool that can do what I want. The goal of this is so that we can reduce the payload sent to the client from the server without breaking functionality or styles.